# How to fix a garbage disposal pipe leak?

Tags: leak, pipe, garbage-disposal

I have a slowly dripping joint where the disposal meets the drain pipe. I want to fix it myself and thought to just seal it with some sealant. What sealant should I use and/or should I not seal it, but use another technique? 
Complete noob here.[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is probably a gasket under that hold down flange. Buy a replacement gasket. Then remove the flange, use sand paper to remove any corrosion until you have a smooth, bright metal surface, then install the new gasket, and screw the flange back in.